# How to get more than 7 dimensions and 10 metrics from the Google Analytics API

Tags: node.js, google-analytics

Is it possible, to get data from Google Analytics that contain more than the usual limits found in the Google Analytics API.

I am using `node-googleanalytics` library to pull data from Google Analytics for use in node.js projects. When I querying more than 7 dimension or more than 10 dimension an error message is displayed `[Error: Requested 8 dimensions; only 7 are allowed.]` or `[Error: Requested 11 metrics; only 10 are allowed.]`. Is it possible to get more than 7 dimensions and 10 metrics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are limits imposed by the Core Reporting API for Google Analytics. The [latest Reference Guide (v3)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#dimensions) specifies:

- You can supply a maximum of 7 dimensions in any query.
- You can supply a maximum of 10 metrics for any query.

Comment: I know that also.But does google have any option [even paid form] to allow more then 7 dimensions?

Comment: I think it is due possible query length which is formed as a get request. Querystring max length is around 2000 odd charaters.
I have even facing the problem with less then 7 dimension but having some filters which eventually increasing the limit far from 2000 characters.
So what i does is send multiple queries to fetch the data.

Comment: Your answer if in the question title.

Answer (score 2):

In regards to dimensions, the limits are fixed (i.e. a maximum of 7 dimensions for any query) but there are programmatic workarounds.  If you have specific dimensions that can be used to identify a user (e.g. a session ID and browser timestamp), you can execute multiple queries then patch them together.

I built a python program that will do exactly this: https://github.com/aiqui/ga-download

This program can bring together multiple groups of dimensions, so that any number of dimensions can be downloaded and combined into a single CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Soulution might be to play with Reports in Google, create what you need and than you can pull reports with:
Google Analytics Data API (GA4)
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1

in there you can have dimensions and metrics you need.
This works at this point only for Google Analytics 4.

And in [quickstart you have Node.js client](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#node.js_1) which uses Google Analytics Data API to query a Google Analytics 4 property.